# MSSql LocalDB v14.0 - cannot automatically create DB-File anymore (after install of new version)

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I had to update my LocalDB instance to the newest version of Sql-Server.

But now - what worked before - stopped working:

ConnectionString is: "(LocalDB)\MSSqlLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyNewDatabase;...."

expected: when one connects first time, and the DB is not available, it is created in a default location (according to MS in "%USERPROFILE%").

This worked fine before I installed the newest version (SqlExpress 2017).
Now, when I do this, I get an exception that SQL-Server cannot create the file:

"C:\users\johannes.colmseeMyNewDataBase.mdf" <-- check the folder...there is one backslash missing!!!

any idea how to fix this?

Update:
I had to install SQL-Express (2016 I think...) to a new system, which had no prior install of any MS-SQL product...that install has the same kind of problems - so it is *not* related to update-install in any way....

Comment: Maybe check the datadirectory reg value here:  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\

Comment: The datadirectory was fine - I deleted all other LocalDB instances (the siblings of the node you directed me to)...let's see if this helps in any way. *Update* It did not.

Comment: Yeap. That's a known [bug](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191393/97345). The workaround is to explicitly specify the path to the data files on database creation, which is annoying, but I'm not aware of any permanent fix.